# Proof that every finite subset of a metric space is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces

I need to show that every finite subset of a metric space is closed. I make use of the following propositions:

**Prop. 1:** Given a metric space $(X,d)$, $x\in X$, and $r\ge0$. Then, the closed ball $\bar{B}(x,r)=\left\{y\in X:d(x,y)\le r\right\}$ is a closed set in $(X,d)$.

**Prop. 2:** The finite union of closed sets in $(X,d)$ is closed in $(X,d)$.

Theorem. Every finite subset of a metric space $(X,d)$ is closed.

*Proof.* Let $A\subseteq X$ be arbitrary and finite. Then $A=\left\{a_i:i\in\{1,2,...,n\}\right\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$. Consider the set $A_i\subseteq A$ such that $A_i=\{a_i\}$ with $a_i\in A$. Note that by Prop. 1 the closed ball $\bar{B}(a_i,0)=\{a_i\}$ is a closed set. So since $A=A_1\cup A_2\cup ...\cup A_n$ is the finite union of closed sets, by Prop. 2 then $A$ is closed.

Is this proof right? I'm very dubious about the use I'm making of Prop. 1, since I'm not 100% convinced that calling the closed ball $B(a_i,0)$ shows that $\{a_i\}$ for arbitrary $a_i\in A$ is closed.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Let $(X, d) $ be a metric space. 

1) $\{x\}$ is closed in $(X, d) $

Proof: Let $x_0\in X\setminus \{x\}$.

Then $$d:=d(x, x_0) >0$$Now choose an open ball $B(x_0, \frac{d}{2}) $.Then $B(x_0, \frac{d}{2}) \subset X\setminus \{x\}$. Hence $ X\setminus \{x\}$ is open implies $\{x\}$ is closed. 

2) $A=\bigcup_{a\in A}\{a\}$ 

$|A|<\infty$ implies $A$ is closed since each singleton subset is closed and finite union of closed sets is closed.

Answer (score 2):

check the complementary is open:
$A^c=X-\cup \{x_i\},\;i \in\{1,...,n\}$.
$A, X$ being the finite set and the metric space respectively.

then since the set is finite:
$d(x_i, x_j)=r_{ij}>0,\;i\neq j$.
take the minimum of $r=min(r_{ij})$.

let $x$ be a point which is not $x_i,\;\forall i \in \{1,...,n\}$.
then there exists a ball centered on $x$ which does not include any of $x_i$, namely $B_{r/2}(x)$.
thus $B_{r/2}(x)\subseteq A^c$.
Thus $A^c$ is open.

Correction following comment from @Maksim.
Take $r=\min{d(x,x_i)}$, then $B_{r/2}\subseteq A^c$.

Comment: Are you sure with the choice of $r$ ? Let $A:=\{0,2\}\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $x:=1/10$. Then  $r=2$ and $B_{r/2}(0.1)$ is not a subset of $A^c$ as it still contains $0$.

Comment: I stand corrected, take $r=\min {d(x,x_i)}$ then, $B_{r/2}\subseteq A^c$.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is entirely sound, assuming the two propositions.

Just for the record, I would answer the question like this: by definition, a subset of a metric space is *closed* if it contains all of its limit points. Say that $A \subseteq X$ is finite and not closed. Then it doesn't contain one of its limit points $x$. Then, take an arbitrary ball around $x$, and find a point $a_1$ of $A$ in that ball. Now take a ball of radius $d(x,a_1)/2$ of $x$, and find a point $a_2$ in that ball. Of course, $a_2 \neq a_1$ by the condition we put on the radius. Continue this way to get an infinite sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$ of distinct points of $A$, which contradicts the fact that $A$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct, however I would reformulate it a bit:

Let $A=\{a_i: i=1,...,n\}$ with $a_i\in A$.
So $A=\cup_{i=1}^n \{a_i\} = \cup_{i=1}^n \bar{B}(a_i,0) $. The right hand side of this equation is a finite union of closed sets, so from Prop.2 it follows that $A$ is closed.

BTW you can avoid using Prop 2 by considering that for any $x \notin A $ we have  $\delta_x:= \min \{d(x,a_i): i=1,..,n \} $ being clearly positive and therefore the open set $B_{\delta_x}(x)$
is not intersecting with $A$. In other words the complement of $A$ is open, thus proving that $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to prove that the complement is open. Let $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ be a finite set. Then for $x$ in the complement, Let $m=\text{min}(d(x,x_1),...,d(x,x_n))$.

Then the open ball of radius $m$ around $x$ doesn't contain any point of the finite set. Since this can be done for all $x$ in the complement, the complement is open and, therefore, the finite set is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this property holds in any Hausdorff space $X$, as singleton sets are closed in Hausdorff spaces.

To see why, observe that any set is the union of its singletons, i.e., for $U\subseteq X$, we have $U=\bigcup_{u\in U}\{u\}$.

It follows from basic topology that the finite union of closed sets is closed; to demonstrate in this case, we simply observe that if $U$ is finite then $$X\setminus U= \bigcap_{u\in U}(X\setminus\{u\})$$ is a finite intersection of open sets, hence open.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct, your slight doubts about your proposition 1 being unfounded.

For *any* real number $r$ (and any point $x$), the subset $\bar{B}(x,r)=\left\{y\in X:d(x,y)\le r\right\}$ is closed, including for $r=0$ where it is a singleton (and even for negative $r$'s where it is empty).

This is because $\bar{B}(x,r)$ is the inverse image of the closed subset $[0,r]$ of $\mathbb R$ by the continuous map $X\to\mathbb R,\;
y\mapsto d(x,y)$.